# Cython: How to expose void* and function pointer in struct?

Tags: python, pointers, function-pointers, cython

I have a C header with:

```
typedef struct
{    
      <normal members>
      void (*cb_func)(glp_tree *T, void *info);
      void *cb_info;
      <normal members>
} glp_iocp;
```

Currently, in my pxd file:

```
ctypedef struct IntOptCP "glp_iocp":
    <normal members>
    int out_dly     #  mip.out_dly (milliseconds)
    #void (*cb_func)(Tree* tree, void* info)
                    #  mip.cb_func
    #void* cb_info   #  mip.cb_info
    <normal members>
```

In a pyx file, at some point, I do (essentially):

```
cdef class MyClass:

    IntOptCP _iocp

    <__cintit__ and the like>

    def some_method(self):
        <manipulation of self._iocp>
        controls = dict()
        controls = self._iocp
        return controls
```

This works nicely. However, now I also wish to expose `cb_func` and `cb_info`. This then breaks the assignment to controls. What I would like to have is two python object types (classes?), one for `cb_func` and one for `cb_info`, instances of which can be passed through to `cb_func` and `cb_info` arguments of the `glp_iocp` struct.

I have read https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Demos/callback (and have used pycapsule), but nevertheless, I am too inexperienced/unfamiliar with Cython to see how I can use that information for my specific case.

So, any help and pointers on how to (best) expose `cb_func` and `cb_info` are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you can expose `cb_func` and `cb_info` doing something similar to this toy example:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef void (*f_type)(int, double*, double*)

ctypedef struct IntOptCP:
    int a
    double *b
    double *c
    f_type f

cdef class MyClass:
    cdef IntOptCP _iocp
    def exec_f(self):
        self._iocp.f(self._iocp.a, self._iocp.b, self._iocp.c)

cdef void myfunc(int a, double *b, double *c):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(a):
        b[i] += 1
        c[i] += 1

def main():
    cdef f_type f
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] b, c
    cdef int a
    a = 100
    b = np.zeros(a, dtype=np.float64)
    c = np.zeros(a, dtype=np.float64)
    test = MyClass()
    test._iocp.a = a
    test._iocp.b = &b[0]
    test._iocp.c = &c[0]
    test._iocp.f = myfunc
    print 'before', a, b, c
    test.exec_f()
    print 'after', a, b, c
```

Comment: Using your instructions, I managed to get things formulated so that they compile. Actually testing the code may take a while, so you'll have to be patient before I can select this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @equaeghe hope you had time to test the answer...let me know your feedback.

Comment: Not yet. I will accept your answer; your efforts deserve recognition even if I cannot find the time to sufficiently evaluate them.